# how to search and replace in NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a JSON that I converted into NSDictionary and now I want to search and replace some values in it but I have no idea how to to this,

```
{  
   "CODE":200,
   "APICODERESULT":"USER_INTERESTS",
   "MESSAGE":"user interests fetched successfully",
   "VALUE":{  
      "Books":[  
         {  
            "key":"7",
            "value":"Fiction",
            "selected":true
         },
         {  
            "key":"8",
            "value":"Romantic",
            "selected":true
         }
      ],
      "Music":[  
         {  
            "key":"11",
            "value":"Classical",
            "selected":false
         },
         {  
            "key":"12",
            "value":"Jazz",
            "selected":false
         },
         {  
            "key":"10",
            "value":"Pop",
            "selected":false
         },
         {  
            "key":"13",
            "value":"Western",
            "selected":false
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

here I have the value for `key` that I want to search in the dictionary and when I found that key with the value that I have I want to replace the value for `selected` in the same block.

**For example:-**

I have value 10 for `key` then I want to change the value for key selected to true 
so the it will look like this

```
{  
   "CODE":200,
   "APICODERESULT":"USER_INTERESTS",
   "MESSAGE":"user interests fetched successfully",
   "VALUE":{  
      "Books":[  
         {  
            "key":"7",
            "value":"Fiction",
            "selected":true
         },
         {  
            "key":"8",
            "value":"Romantic",
            "selected":true
         }
      ],
      "Music":[  
         {  
            "key":"11",
            "value":"Classical",
            "selected":false
         },
         {  
            "key":"12",
            "value":"Jazz",
            "selected":false
         },
         {  
            "key":"10",
            "value":"Pop",
            "selected":true
         },
         {  
            "key":"13",
            "value":"Western",
            "selected":false
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: that huge JSON all in one line doesn't help us understand what you want. I've kept scrolling for about 5 times and I still couldn't spot the difference. Explain what you want and/or post a **minimal** example demonstrating your needs.

Comment: Please use http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to format json because I can't post question with that huge json

Comment: no I won't. Do you understand the word "minimal"? **you** reduce the size of the JSON so that only the relevant parts remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your input dictionary as mainDictionary and use following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *valuesDic = [mainDictionary objectForKey:@"VALUES"];


NSArray *allPossibleKeysArray = [valuesDic allKeys];

for (int j=0; j<allPossibleKeysArray.count; j++) {

    NSString *keyStr = [allPossibleKeysArray objectAtIndex:j];

    NSArray *array = [valuesDic objectForKey:keyStr];

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"]];

        if([keyString isEqualToString:keyvalue]){

            [dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"selected"];
            [dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:@"selected"];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: bookArray won't return mutable dictionary, but `NSDictionary`

Comment: But I have not the value `Books` where i want to do this and this `Book` is not fixed it can be anything else all that I have is value for `key` like 10, 11, 15 etc. and these are unique .

Comment: @Varun I have updated answer, please check. Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I thought it should work but it didn't don't know why

Comment: The last line will produce error: `-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: no there is no error in the code but not changing dictionary value as I NSLog that dictionary but it is same as before

Comment: @torap you don't need to remove the key before setting the corresponding value…

Answer (score 1):

You should make such changes during parsing the JSON/moving it into model. The code below is a workaround:

```
NSDictionary *initialJson = //Your JSON here
NSArray *allSubKeys= [initialJson[@"Value"] allKeys];

// Your mutable output.
NSMutableDictionary *mutableJson = [initialJson mutableCopy]

for(NSString *key in allSubKeys) {//Music && Books
    // Create another cointainer here
    for(NSArray *arr in mutableJson[@"Value][key]) {
       // Create another cointainer here           
       for(NSDictionary *dict in arr) {//key, value, selected
           for (NSString *key2 in [dict allKeys]) {
               if ([key2 isEqualToString:@"selected"] && [dict[@"value"] equals:@10]) {
                   // Save YES here
               }
               else {
                   // Just copy element
               }
               // Add object to parent container
           }
           // Add object to parent container
       }
       // Add object to parent container           
    }
    // Add object to parent container
}
```

Comment: there many type error I fixed them and checking now will get back to you soon

Comment: `for (NSString *key2 in [dict allKeys]) {` here dict is only containing `@"selected"` and application is crashing at this point

Answer (score 1):

Here is full solution

```
NSString* str=@"{\"CODE\":200,\"APICODERESULT\":\"USER_INTERESTS\",\"MESSAGE\":\"user interests fetched successfully\",\"value\":{\"Books\":[{\"key\":\"7\",\"value\":\"Fiction\",\"selected\":true},{\"key\":\"8\",\"value\":\"Romantic\",\"selected\":true}],\"Music\":[{\"key\":\"11\",\"value\":\"Classical\",\"selected\":false},{\"key\":\"12\",\"value\":\"Jazz\",\"selected\":false},{\"key\":\"10\",\"value\":\"Pop\",\"selected\":false},{\"key\":\"13\",\"value\":\"Western\",\"selected\":false}]}}";
    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"dictionary before updating: %@", dictionary);
    // copy old dict
    NSMutableDictionary* newDict=[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
    [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dictionary];
    // get the entry to be changed
    NSMutableDictionary* valueDict=[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
    [valueDict addEntriesFromDictionary:newDict[@"value"]];
    NSMutableArray* musicArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    [musicArray addObjectsFromArray:newDict[@"value"][@"Music"]];
    // get the music array and change your property
    NSMutableDictionary* musicDict2=[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [musicDict2 addEntriesFromDictionary:[musicArray objectAtIndex:2]];
    [musicDict2 setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"selected"];
    [musicArray replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:musicDict2];
    // update the value dictionary
    [valueDict setObject:musicArray forKey:@"Music"];
    //update the new dictionary
    [newDict setObject:valueDict forKey:@"value"];
    NSLog(@"dictionary after updating: %@", newDict);
```

Comment: I already told that I don't have the value `Music` it is dynamic and can be change according to web service

Comment: okz.. but you can make it dynamic by just adding dynamic string instead of music

Comment: but how I can get that dynamic string if I don't know what will be coming ?

Comment: varun you have to specify some value for sure like in torap answer its keyvalue